# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Sync_Helper_Data::updateMagProduct() while method exist

Tags: php, magento, undefined

I'm creating a Magento extension, where I use a custom Helper class to reuse some methods in my controller function. Everything was working fine, until I added a new method in my helper class.

Where I call this method, I get this error:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Art_Sync_Helper_Data::updateMagProduct() in /home/vagrant/apps/default/app/code/local/Art/Sync/controllers/ProductUpdateController.php on line 259
```

That's this line:

```
$product_id = self::$helperData->updateMagProduct($product);
```

But I already defined it at top of my controller:

```
private static $helperData;
```

And in my indexAction() method:
(Same method where the error occurs. ($product_id=self::....) )

```
self::$helperData = Mage::helper('sync/data');
```

I thought, my function in my helper class wasn't correct, but it seems ok...

```
public static function updateMagProduct($product)
{// code...}
```

Actually, all my previous methods I added are working...
I tried also to add a new method that returns a simple String, but also that wouldn't work.

So, my question, do you know what could going wrong?
There is a limit in functions you can use in Magento / Zend helper classes?

== UPDATE ==
Controller + indexAction method: 
`class Art_Sync_ProductUpdateController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

```
private static $helper;
private static $helperData;

public function indexAction()
{
        self::$helper = Mage::helper('farmadsync/util');
        self::$helperData = Mage::helper('farmadsync/data');
        self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Started product & category UPDATE service.');

        // get store languages
        $default_nl = Mage::getStoreConfig('farmadsync/store/store_nl');
        $store_fr = Mage::getStoreConfig('farmadsync/store/store_fr');
        $store_en = Mage::getStoreConfig('farmadsync/store/store_en');
        $store_de = Mage::getStoreConfig('farmadsync/store/store_de');

        // check if valid URL
        $errors = false;
        if(!isset($_GET['guid']) || empty($_GET['guid']) || $_GET['guid'] != self::$helper->getGUID())
        {
            self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Product syncronisation without valid GUID! Aborting... || GET params: ' .print_r($_GET,true));
            self::$helper->outputMessagesToBrowser();
            $errors = true;
        }

        if(!$errors)
        {
            // set maintenance flag
            //$maintenance_flag = Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'maintenance.flag';
            //touch($maintenance_flag);

            // disable indexer
            self::$helper->disableIndexer();

            // get version info from last update by Farmad
            $farmad_version_info = Mage::getModel('farmadsync/versioninfo')->load(1);
            $cat_version = $farmad_version_info->getCategoryVersion();
            $prodInfo_version = $farmad_version_info->getProductinfosVersion();

            // get categories
            $cat_version = $cat_version + 1;
            $farmad_categories = self::$helperData->getFarmadCategories($cat_version);

            // get productinfo
            self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Preparing product updates.');
            $prodInfo_version = $prodInfo_version + 1;
            //
            $soapClient = self::$helper->initSoap();
            $farmad_products = array();
            $result = $soapClient->GetProductInfosDelta(array(
                'guid'=>self::$helper->getGUID(),
                'webshopId'=>self::$helper->getWebshopID(),
                'yourCurrentVersion'=>$prodInfo_version,
            ));

            if($result && $result->GetProductInfosDeltaResult)
            {
                $farmad_products = $result->GetProductInfosDeltaResult->ProductInfos->ProductInfo;
            }

            if($farmad_products==null)
            {
                // no product updates
                self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: There are no product updates.');
            }
            else
            {
                // get updated products
                self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Get updated products.');
                //
                    // only one result
                    // check if deleted
                    if($farmad_products->IsDeleted)
                    {
                        set_time_limit(120);
                        // delete product
                        self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Product with cnk: '.$farmad_products->Cnk.' is deleted in Farmad. Deleting product in Magento...');
                        // get existing magento product from farmad cnk
                        $mag_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('SKU',$farmad_products->Cnk);
                        Mage::register('isSecureArea',true);
                        $mag_product->delete();
                        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
                        self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Product is successful deleted.');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // check if product is obsolete
                        if($farmad_products->Obsolete)
                        {
                            set_time_limit(120);
                            // product is obsolete
                            // delete product
                            self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Product with cnk'.$farmad_products->Cnk.' is obsolete in Farmad. Deleting product in Magento...');
                            // get existing magento product from farmad cnk
                            $mag_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('SKU',$farmad_products->Cnk);
                            Mage::register('isSecureArea',true);
                            $mag_product->delete();
                            Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
                            self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Product is successful deleted.');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            set_time_limit(500);
                            // update product
                            self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Ready to update product with cnk: '. $farmad_products->Cnk);
                            $product_id = Crmart_Farmadsync_Helper_Data::updateMagProduct($farmad_products);
                            //$product_id = self::$helperData->updateMagProduct($farmad_products);
                            // import different languages
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                // ...
            }
            //
            //...
        }

}
```

} `

Helper method: 
`class Art_Sync_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

```
private static $helper;

public static function updateMagProduct($farmad_product)
{
    self::$helper = Mage::helper('farmadsync/util');
    $isNewProduct = false;
    //
    // category didn't exist yet, so we create the category
    $mag_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$farmad_product->Cnk);
    if(!$mag_product)
    {
        $mag_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $isNewProduct = true;
    }
    //
    self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Start creating product with cnk: '.$farmad_product->Cnk.'.');
    // product don't exist
    if(!$isNewProduct)
    {
        // product exist, so update with new values
        // get product categories
        $categoryIDs = array();
        foreach($farmad_product->CategoryIds as $farmad_productcat_id)
        {
            // product assigned to multiple categories
            if(is_array($farmad_productcat_id))
            {
                foreach($farmad_productcat_id as $id)
                {
                    $magentoCat = Mage::getModel('farmadsync/category')->load($id);
                    if(!$magentoCat->hasMagentoCatId())
                    {
                        self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Error while saving product with cnk: '.$farmad_product->Cnk.'. The category isnt found in the shop.');
                        return -1;
                    }
                    array_push($categoryIDs, $magentoCat->getMagentoCatId());
                    self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Added category to product.');
                }
            }
            else // product has only one category
            {
                $magentoCat = Mage::getModel('farmadsync/category')->load($farmad_productcat_id);
                if(!$magentoCat->hasMagentoCatId())
                {
                    self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Error while saving product with cnk: '.$farmad_product->Cnk.'. The category isn\'t found in the shop.');
                    return -1;
                }
                array_push($categoryIDs, $magentoCat->getMagentoCatId());
                self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Added category to product.');
            }

        }
        //
        $mag_product
            ->setStoreId('default')
            ->setCategoryIds($categoryIDs)
            ->setPrice((float)$farmad_product->SalesPriceWithVatWithoutDiscount)
            ->setName($farmad_product->DescriptionNl)
            ->setUrlKey('')
            ->setDescription($farmad_product->DescriptionNl)
            ->setShortDescription($farmad_product->DescriptionNl)
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
            ->setFarmadsyncIsMedicine($farmad_product->Medicine)
            ->setFarmadsyncNeedsPrescription($farmad_product->NeedsPrescription)
            ->setFarmadsyncLeafletUrl($farmad_product->LeafletUrl_Nl)
            ->setFarmadsyncVersion($farmad_product->Version)
            ->setFarmadsyncObsolete($farmad_product->Obsolete);

        $discountPercentage = (float)$farmad_product->DiscountPercentage;
        if($discountPercentage!=0)
        {
            $price = (float)$farmad_product->SalesPriceWithVatWithoutDiscount;
            $discountPrice = $price*((100.0 - $discountPercentage)/100.0);
            $mag_product->setSpecialPrice($discountPrice);
            self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Added discount percentage to product.');
        }

        $taxclassId = null;
        switch((int)$farmad_product->VatPercentage)
        {
            case 6:
                $taxclassId = Mage::getStoreConfig('farmadsync/tax/taxclass_6_percent');
                break;
            case 21:
                $taxclassId = Mage::getStoreConfig('farmadsync/tax/taxclass_21_percent');
                break;
            default:
                self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Could not dectect tax class - Product '.$farmad_product->Cnk.' not imported');
                return -1;
                break;
        }
        $mag_product->setTaxClassId($taxclassId);
        self::$helper->log('Farmadsync: Added tax class to product.');

        // save:
        try
        {
            $mag_product->save();
            self::$helper->log('FarmadSync: Finished updating product with cnk: ' . $farmad_product->Cnk);
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            self::$helper->log('FarmadSync: Error while updating product with cnk: ' . $farmad_product->Cnk . '; ' . $ex->getMessage());
            return -1;
        }
    }
    //
    return $mag_product->getId();
}
```

}`

=== UPDATE 2 ===
I think I found it. Now, I need to solve it.
If I Cmd+click on the method `helperData` I got the following screen:
`Choose Declaration:`
`- helperData Art_Sync_ProductUpdateController .../includes/src/Art/Sync/Controllers`
`- helperData Art_Sync_ProductUpdateController .../app/code/local/Art/Sync/controllers`
But, how can I force to get one declaration? 
(If I click on one of the declarations, it opens in the same class.) 
=== UPDATE 3: SOLVED ===
Ok. Everything was ok in my code.
I must deactivate `Compilation`in Magento... Now, it's running without errors. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Everything was ok in my code.

I must deactivate Compilationin Magento... Now, it's running without errors. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the helper in config.xml? Something like below;

```
...
<global>
    <helpers>
        <sync>
            <class>Art_Sync_Helper</class>
        </sync>
    </helpers>
</global>
...
```

Try calling your method with `Mage::helper('sync')->updateMagProduct($product);`

Comment: Yes, I did.  
My other methods, I created last week, are executed correct. It are only the new methods I added today to the helper class that won't work.  
`<global>   
        <helpers>  
            <sync>  
                <class>Art_Sync_Helper</class>  
            </sync>  
        </helpers>`

Comment: Ok, only other thing I can think of is the function is static so try removing the static bit and try again. Static functions are normally called with `Art_Sync_Helper::updateMagProduct($product)`.

Comment: Oops. Typo above static function should be called with `Art_Sync_Helper_Data::updateMagProduct($product)`. Also, post your full code for each class if you can, it's hard to work out what could be the cause without all of it.

Comment: I tried now: `Art_Sync_Helper::updateMagProduct($product)`, and now I get more information from my editor (phpstorm):  
`Multiple definitions exist for class Art_Sync_Helper  
- Undefined class: Declaration of referenced class is not found in built-in library and project files.`

Comment: Yeah, need the full code. Check that your helper class name looks like `class Art_Sync_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`. Sounds like you have an incorrect class name if you can't call it statically. Also check you don't have two classes (files) with the same definition like the error suggests.